# MVC4 JQuery Datepicker to capture date from input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, datepicker

Has anybody got experience using jquery ui's datepicker with Razor `@Html.TextBoxFor(...)`

I trying to allow the user to select date using Razor mark up to generate a textbox, when clicked will display Datepicker from jquery UI. I'm not sure if by using:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New","Order"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderInfo.installdate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderInfo.installdate, new {@id="dp"})
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dp").datepicker();
    });
</script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Ran in this order, and no matter rearrange, unable to display the datepicker.

Can this even be done this way?

Comment: Have you also included jquery (not just jqueryui)?

Comment: jquery include is on the bottom of my layout I have updated the order

Comment: The order should be 1) jquery, 2) jquery-ui, 3) your script

Comment: What you have should work. Are there any errors on the debug console?

Comment: Such a simple task. Yet still not able to render. No errors on debug console, but jQuery is not even loaded since I am unable to even `alert("hello");` on my page. People on the web says script renders should be at the bottom of the page, it works neither top nor bottom

Comment: What does your full view look like?

Comment: I've updated my view to show the current order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've bundled the resources

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js");
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/themes/base").Include(
    "~/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
    ...
);
```

Include them in the proper order

Layout.cshtml

```
<html>
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/themes/base")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @RenderSection("page_scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Now the View... Since the scripts were included on the Layout the view doesn't need it.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.installdate, new { @id="dp" })

@section page_scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dp").datepicker({ ... });
        });
    </script>
}
```

If you don't have it on the Layout or don't use one then

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.installdate, new { @id="dp" })

@Styles.Render("~/bundles/themes/base")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dp").datepicker({ ... });
    });
</script>
```